# EC2 webcrawlers

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to gather some data for an experiment I'm running. I have a webscraper that I'd like to run on lots of Amazon EC2 instances and then dump the data into S3 so that I can analyze it later.

Currently I have the code written in ruby, but can easily write it in another language. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How would you go about doing what? What are you have trouble with? Writing the code in another language? You need to ask for solutions to specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

For writing to S3 use the Rightaws gem, it has a really good s3 interface:
http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/right_aws_gem_doc/

Your process will probably look like:

- Gather data
- Write to some intermediate on each node
- Send the file to S3 (using a unique naming scheme)
- Repeat

Alternatively, use a database. Then everything is in the same place. You could use something like mongodb, because it's schema-less, but you can still have useful indexes (eg, a domain index). This is good up to millions of rows.

If you put stuff in s3 it'll just be flat files, so searching through the data at the other end is going to take a long time.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create a database in s3 or do I need to make that in one of the EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of scraper in the market

scrapy is one of the best tool.
its pretty simple

scrapinghub.com